# When an item is pushed to useState array, it's pushing twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an issue with pushing an item to array inside the `useState` hook. When I try to push one element, it pushing twice. Code below:

```
export default function App() {
  const [max, updateMax] = React.useState([]);
  const [mid, updateMid] = React.useState([]);
  const [low, updateLow] = React.useState([]);

  const arr = [
    { letter: "A", number: 100 },
    { letter: "B", number: 80 },
    { letter: "C", number: 60 },
    { letter: "D", number: 40 }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    arr.map((element, index, array) => {
      element.number === 100
        ? updateMax((prevState) => [...prevState, element.letter])
        : element.number >= 60
        ? updateMid((prevState) => [...prevState, element.letter])
        : element.number < 60
        ? updateLow((prevState) => [...prevState, element.letter])
        : null;
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(max, mid, low);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

In console:

```
["A", "A"]
["B", "C", "B", "C"]
["D", "D"]
```

Expected output:

```
["A"]
["B", "C"]
["D"]
```

Why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Is this within a NextJS application?

Comment: Nope, just vanilla

Comment: You're certainly using `<StrictMode>` which runs your `useEffect` twice on development mode only.

Comment: Should I disable `<StrictMode>`?

Comment: Or there are other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it runs twice is because you're running your app in [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Since React 18, developers of React decided to make `useEffect()` run twice when the app uses Strict Mode to help debugging `useEffect()`. If you get unexpected results from it running twice, it means that your code has some kind of smaller or bigger problem, either lack of proper cleanup code, or a little messy logic.

In your case, `useEffect()` is not the best fit for what you're trying to do. Try `useMemo()` instead.

Comment: I think it can even be a `.filter` when he initialize his states :)

Comment: @dbuchet not sure how static `arr` should be. If it's gonna be unchangeable, then a regular `const` outside the component will be enough (and the best in terms of performance).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this is happening due to the `[...prevState,..]` assignment. It could be possible that your `useEffect` fires twice, which in turn makes the function run twice.

One thing you can do to avoid duplicate items in your arrays, is to add a precondition to your `update` calls.

```
const isLetterAlreadyPresent = (arrayToCheck: string[], letterToCheck: string) => {
    return arrayToCheck.some((letter) => letter === letterToCheck));
}

useEffect(() => {
    arr.forEach((element, index, array) => {
      if (element.number === 100 && !isLetterAlreadyPresent(max, element.letter) {
         updateMax((prevState) => [...prevState, element.letter])
      } else if (element.number >= 60 && !isLetterAlreadyPresent(mid, element.letter)){
         updateMid((prevState) => [...prevState, element.letter])
      } else if (element.number < 60 && !isLetterAlreadyPresent(low, element.letter)) {
         updateLow((prevState) => [...prevState, element.letter])
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I also changed the `map` for a `forEach`, since you weren't using the result array that was given by the `map`, nor were you transforming anything within it. In order to iterate over an array, a `forEach` should suffice.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem and misguides about the reason.

Comment: What is the `string` ?